# How to change background color outside path drawn with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I filled my raster map using the `geom_raster()` command. Then I overlaid a closed path on the map using the `geom_path()` command. The result is shown below:

[image]

I would like to make the area outside the perimeter white. This is the command I used to produce the result above (`gg.opzioni` is a list with graphic commands for the raster):

```
r.pred = ggplot(r.pred) + gg.opzioni + geom_path(data = bound.f, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))
```

Comment: is there any chance we could have a [mcve] ... ?? (Packing everything you did to make the raster green into `gg.opzioni`, which we can't see, is a little frustrating ...).  Perhaps you want `geom_polygon` with `fill` specified as an aesthetic, to set the colour *inside* the path?

Comment: @BenBolker my map is full of pixels of different colors. This isn’t the real map, but I thought it was enough to get an answer. So I’ve got pixels also outside the perimeter, but I’m not interested in them. I added the perimeter after the pixels and it’s not in the scale of the pixels. So I thought it was easier to remove the unwanted part of the plot.

Comment: I think it will be easier to clip the raster: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61243/clipping-raster-in-r; https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics/lidar-raster-data-r/crop-raster-data-in-r/

Comment: The first link solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: Since that link is not on Stack Overflow, it would be great if you wrote up a short solution and posted it as an answer to your own question.